# filerobot image editor getCurrentImgData

Tags: npm, next.js

I implemented the Filerobot lib in my next.js site. I copied the example from the Github page. It works fine. Know i want to get the current modified image as base64, without pressing the save button. In the docs i found something like this 'getCurrentImgData'. But i cant get it working. Has someone an example?

https://github.com/scaleflex/filerobot-image-editor#react-example

I tried to acces the method via useref() but i only get null.